# adding to json file instead of adding changes data

Tags: php, arrays, json, oop, data-structures

I have a method that implements writing to a json file,

```
public function setJsonContent(array $data): void
{
    if (file_exists('data/db.json')) {
        $content = $this->getJsonContent();
        if ($content) {
            $data = array_merge($data, $content);
        }
    }
    file_put_contents('data/db.json', json_encode($data));
}
```

it also has a method for getting this file and data from it.

```
public function getJsonContent()
{
    $json = file_get_contents('data/db.json');
    return json_decode($json, true);
}
```

in another class, I have a method that receives data from the user and writes them

```
    $userName = $input->getUserInput('Please, enter user name: ');
    $group = $input->getUserInput('Please, enter group: ');
    $age = $input->getUserInput('Please, enter age: ');

    $this->getJson()->setJsonContent([ $userName => $group, 'age' => $age ]);
```

the first run will write

```
Please, enter user name: qqq
Please, enter group: www
Please, enter age: eee
```

`{"qqq":"www","age":"eee"}`

the next run will write

```
Please, enter user name: aaa
Please, enter group: sss
Please, enter age: ddd
```

`{"aaa":"sss","age":"eee","qqq":"www"}`

**question:** how to structure the data record so that something like

```
{
  "name": [
    "group",
    "age"
  ],
  "name2": [
    "group",
    "age"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the structure of the data that you pass around, make it an array with the name as the key for a sub array with the group and age (no keys for these last 2)...

```
$this->getJson()->setJsonContent([ $userName => [$group, $age ]]);
```

Comment: Thank you, what you need, you don’t know by chance how to indent, otherwise saving now goes on one line

Comment: now ```{"qqq2":["www2","eee2"],"qqq":["www","eee"]}```

Comment: Just add `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` to `file_put_contents('data/db.json', json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));`